# Getting an HTML table to "squish"

Tags: html, css, html-table

My employer has wanted me to take a table that we had on our site and make it more responsive.  My solution was to make the table react as detailed in a previous question of mine ([Responsive Table Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880391/responsive-table-display))

After I went through an implemented that design, I was informed they actually just want the 5 column table "squished" so that it retains all five columns but just has them fit within the viewport, specifically on mobile.

My HTML looks basically like this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Being that I am completely self-taught and have been doing this for a few months now, what can I do to make the table compress its full width in mobile view?

Comment: Why not make it horizontally scrollable?

Comment: As much as I would like to do that, my boss is adamant about it resizing.

Comment: Set all the `<th>`s and `<td>`s to `width: 20%;`, and set `<table>` to `width: 100%;`.

Comment: @axionevolved if you really want it to resize you're better off using CSS grid to create the "table"

Answer (score 0):

If your table is contained within an element that is 100% of the screen's width you would set the table's width to `100%`. If the table's container is not necessarily 100% of the screen's width you could set the table's width to `100vw`. The `vw` unit represents a percentage of the total viewport width. It is not supported in IE8 or lower.

If their width is left unspecified, the columns will be automatically expanded to fit the table's width.

Using the media query from your previous question:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px),(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
    table {
        width: 100%; /* or 100vw depending on the rest of your HTML */
    }
...
}
```

If you need to control the column widths, you can do that by either setting the `th` and `td`s to a fixed percentage width (that sums to 100), or by modifying the `table-layout` property. Setting your table to `table-layout: fixed;` will space all columns equally.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and try this.  I'll update when I can.